# Is there a way to make ALT symbols vertical on HTML

Tags: html, css

Greetings

I would like to make this airplane symbol ( ✈︎ )face up
I tried the below HTML code but not working

```
<p style="writing-mode: vertical-lr;">✈︎</p>
```

Best Regards

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/Lg9hp6qj/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I believe , if you provide width to <p> tag then it should work.

<p style="width: 1%; rotate: 270deg;">✈︎</p>

This worked for me .
```